# Pass variable to Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, templates

I'm using Django and jqGrids, and I'm trying to automate the grid's contruction process. There is an issue, that I can't figure out the solution.

I've a Javascript file that I include in the header of my html page, `grid.locale-en.js`, that contains all strings that appear on the jqGrid's boxes.

```
<script src="{% static 'project/grid.locale-en.js' %}"></script>
```

I want to pass to this file one Django variable that has the name of the grid.

This way, I can have has mutch grids as I want, and I only need one grid's code.
This will serve to change the following fields.

```
edit: {
        addCaption: "Add Product",
        editCaption: "Edit Product",
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 easy ways are:

1. You could have django render your javascript
2. you could set a global JS config variable in your django template and then your JS file could look for the variable.

in django template

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var CONFIG = {};
CONFIG.GRID_NAME = "{{ your name }}";
</script>
```

THen in your js file

you can check to make sure that CONFIG.GRID_NAME is set and use it appropriately.

Comment: You just have the unnecessary `var` attribute. Otherwise, you are correct. Spot on! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a container div

```
<div id="jq-grid-container" data-my-column="{{ variable here }}"></div>
```

Then where you set up your jQGrid, you can just fetch your variable name with

```
var myColumn = $('#jq-grid-container').data('my-column');
```